# How to shift left to the beginning of the previous symbol?

Tags: spacing

I'm trying to do this (this is just an experiment, not a real case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\mapsto\hspace{-1em}\pi$
\end{document}
```

I want `\pi` to start horizontally exactly where the left side of the arrow starts. Of course, I don't know the exact width of the arrow. The width `-1em` in the code above is definitely wrong.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? You could use `$\mathrlap{\mapsto}\pi$` (requires `mathtools` package) and then the content coming after the `\mapsto` will overlap it, starting exactly where it starts, but is that really what you want? `\mapsto` is wider than `\pi`: what do you want to do with what comes after `\pi`? Should it overlap the remainder of `\mapsto` as well (as it will with `\mathrap`)? Would you rather have the `\pi` *centered* overlapping the `\mapsto`, respecting the width of `\mapsto`?

Comment: Why do people keep asking "what is your real problem"? OP says "this is just an experiment" so there shouldn't be a case of XY-like problem here...

Comment: (that having said \mathrlap should be the correct solution here if I interpret OP's question correctly. Although if the requirement involves "can only put new things to the right of the `\mapsto`" then it would be harder, probably impossible without some Lua math-list manipulation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is, if you want to follow next object after the shorter `\pi` or after the longer `\mapsto`. The following example shows both variants:

```
\def\overlap#1#2{\overlapA{#1}{#2}}
\def\overlapA#1#2{\mathrel{\rlap{$#1$}}\mathrel{#2}}

test1: $a \overlap\mapsto \pi 123$.

\def\overlap#1#2{\overlapA{#2}{#1}}

test2: $a \overlap\mapsto \pi 123$.
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be the idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\smapsto}[1]{\mathrel{\mathrlap{#1}}\mapsto}

\begin{document}

$X \smapsto{\pi} Y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you uncomment `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`, you get

[image]

You see that different fonts have different ideas about the bounding box of their glyphs. In either case, the `\mapstochar` symbol has a shorter sidebearing on the left than `\pi`.

We can fix it with an optional argument to move the symbol right (positive argument) or left (negative argument).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\smapsto}[2][0]{\mathrel{\mathrlap{\mspace{#1mu}#2}}\mapsto}

\begin{document}

$X \smapsto[1]{\pi} Y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With NewTX

[image]

and you probably want to move the symbol further to the right. With

```
$X \smapsto[1.5]{\pi} Y$
```

you get

[image]

As you're into experiments, why not trying the following?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\smapsto}[2][0]{\mathrel{\mathrlap{\mspace{#1mu}\mathop{#2}}}\mapsto}

\begin{document}

$X \smapsto[1]{\pi} Y$

\end{document}
```

The symbol will be vertically centered with respect to the math axis, where the arrow stem lies on.

[image]